# Where are 'super', 'class' and 'this' keywords defined in java?

Tags: java, super

This just struck me last night, where exactly are these keywords defined. As an example, lets say we have

```
public class A {
    public void doSomething() {
        // Only for illustration.
        A.super.hashCode(); 
        A.class.getClass();
    }
}
```

From the usage, these keywords 'super', 'class', 'this' looks like static (class level). Are these not static and something else? How does the '.'[dot operator] know it has to behave differently here and not consider them as static.

Comment: They're defined in the Java Language Specification.

Comment: The dot operator doesn't know anything. The Java compilers know how to deal with keywords and operators, and verifies the code respects the Java Language Specification.

Comment: Okay! @JBNizet That makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where exactly are these keywords defined

They are defined in the [Java Language Specification #3.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9).

> From the usage, these keywords 'super', 'class', 'this' looks like static (class level).

No they don't. Consider `a.hashCode()`.

> Are these not static and something else?

Yes and yes.

> How does the '.'[dot operator] know it has to behave differently here and not consider them as static.

Same as for any other object reference. It's a semantic-analysis task.

Comment: I think this could also be useful in addition to what u provided. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2

Comment: @AdityaBahuguna And [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3), but these are not definitions of the keywords.

Comment: Yeah. But these links certainly add to the usage and interpretation of these special keywords which makes more sense given these are special. Thanks!

Comment: @AdityaBahuguna The question was where are they *defined*. All keywords are 'special'.

Comment: Yeah, I think the language of the question and what I intended to ask or was looking for, are not same. The JLS #3.9 looks more like a declaration to me that these are the keywords. Should not a definition include more details than just that? Like these links in the comments give more insight on the usage and semantics of these.

Comment: @AdityaBahuguna You're asking me to comment on your question and/or how the JLS was written. I have no comment to offer.